# Distributed Cache Across Microservice Domains

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, hazelcast, spring-cache

Is managing @CachePut in a different microservice from @Cacheable in a distributed cache environment an anti-pattern?

I'm working on spring boot microservices that are split across two domain categories: data ingestion and UI.  The ingestion is separated from the UI services so that bursts of data will not impact response times.  Once the data is ingested, we fan it out on kafka to a persistence service for storage and a session service for real-time determinations such as user notifications.

To ensure that I can keep up with the ingestion rate, I want to cache the user notification configuration in my ingestion pipeline after the initial REST lookup.  But if a user updates their configuration in the UI (e.g. increase / decrease warning threshold, turn off warnings, change to digest), I want the cache refreshed with that update. Because I will be auto-scaling these services to meet demand, I plan to use distributed cache.

Does splitting @CachePut and @Cacheable across two different microservices in a distributed cache configuration constitute an anti-pattern?  Would sending the objects across kafka constitute a better alternative?

My gut tells me to avoid splitting the cache management across microservices like this because I can imagine someone changing the cache keys in one service and forgetting to change them in the second.   On the other hand, sending them across kafka to a consumer in the session service would look ugly, something like this:

```
@CachePut(value = "config", key = "new SimpleKey(#config.userId, #config.applicationId)")
public UserApplicationConfig fakeSave(UserApplicationConfig config) {
  // not actually saving anything, just need somewhere to put my CachePut annotation
  return config;
}
```

Comment: Why you want to put the items in the cache, if you are fanning out to a Kafka queue, any specific use case?

Comment: Ingestion maintains a session state for business decisions, based on user configuration.  User configuration is maintained through a REST interface.   I don't want to perform a REST call for every ingested message.  The REST interface will only be called if no cached value exists for the user / application key.  But a user can change configuration mid-session, and I need to update the cache with that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is an anti pattern since it breaks the service boundaries, data hiding in particular.

When the user data is updated, you want to update the service clients that have a cached version of your user data. A better design would send an event "User data changes" and let service clients subscribe to it.

With a distributed cache you introduce possible points of failure, latency and configuration options for consistency, which are not simple.

Comment: That's what I was leaning towards, using Hazelcast's Embedded Distributed configuration.  Like you said, preserves the service boundaries, also allows me to only introduce changes to cached objects when an ingestion session is in progress (user could simply be playing with settings while not in a session) and simplifies maintenance and debugging for future developers.

Answer (score 0):

`@CachePut` always lets the method execute. It is generally used if you want your cache to be updated with the result of the method execution.
Example: When you want to update a stale data which is cached, instead of blowing the cache completely.

`@Cacheable` will be executed only once for the given cachekey and subsequent requests won't execute the method, until the cache expires or gets flushed.

This is based upon your design decision. Its not an anti pattern. Spring Data JPA also uses interface repositories with Annotations, this does not mean, there is no need to create the "Fake" interface even.

Its a way to capture the annotation (Annotation Processing).

Comment: Right.  But I have two services: User Application Configuration Service (REST) and Session Service (streaming ingestion pipeline).  Is it distributed cache anti-pattern to maintain CachePut in the first service to update Cacheable values in the second service?